# Analysis by columns in SAS

Tags: statistics, sas, analytics

I need help to analyze the dependence of the objective function (variable: "cus12") on independent variables. I have data that has 1000 columns and the independent variables are divided into 4 groups: app_x, act_x, agr_x, ags_x. I probably need to write a loop to investigate the dependence of the variable "cus12" on variables from the given groups. I have a problem with writing such a loop and entering the appropriate "proc" in it

```
%let src=C:\Users\chlop\Desktop\ProjektSAS;
%let out=C:\Users\chlop\Desktop\ProjektSAS\wyj;
libname src "&src" compress=yes;
libname out "&out" compress=yes;

data out.test;
    set src.train;
    drop app_char_job_code app_char_marital_status app_char_city app_char_home_status app_char_cars act: agr: ags: default_cus3 default_cus6 default_cus9;
    where period<'200405';
run;




proc sort data=names;
by varnum;
run;

%let target = default_cus12; *zmienna objasniana do modelu;


proc sql;
select name
from names
where name ne "app_char_job_code" and name ne "app_char_marital_status" and name ne "app_char_city" and name ne "app_char_home_status" and name ne "app_char_cars" and name ne "cid" and name ne "period" and name ne "&target";
quit;



proc sql;
select name into:zmienne separeted by ' '
from names
where name ne "app_char_job_code" and name ne "app_char_marital_status" and name ne "app_char_city" and name ne "app_char_home_status" and name ne "app_char_cars" and name ne "cid" and name ne "period" and name ne "&target";
quit;

%put &zmienne;


%macro a(lista);
%do i=1 %to 3;
%put %scan(&lista, &i, ' '); *separator na koncu;
%end;
%mend;

%a(&zmienne);


%macro gini(in, target, vars);

data gini_tab;
length zmienna $ 50. gini 8.;
delete;
run; 


proc sql noprint;
select count(*)
into :n
from names;
quit;

%do i=1 %to &n;
%let zm = %scan(&vars, &i,' ');
*separator na koncu, wybieramy kolejne zmienne;



ods output Association=gini;
proc logistic data=&in;
model &target = &zm;
run;
ods output close;


proc sql;
select nValue2 into :g_coef
from gini
where Label2 contains "Somers";
quit;

%put Gini: &zm = &g_coef;

data tmp;
length zmienna $ 50. gini 8.;
zmienna = "&zm";
gini = &g_coef;
run;

proc append base=gini_tab data=tmp force;
run;


%end;

proc sort data=gini_tab;
by descending gini;
run;

%mend;

%gini(src.train, default_cus12, &zmienne);
```

Comment: what problem do you have ?

Comment: I don't know how to start. My idea is as follows: 1. I think I should build a macro and a loop (but all the loops I build don't work). 2. I think I should parse the dependency using "proc logistic" but and don t have macro and loops so I can't try to do anything inside. 3. I wanted to use the Chi-Square and Cramer's V test, but without a good start, I can't try anything else. I am a beginner in SAS. Any help / advice will be useful.

Comment: Are you saying you want to run four models. Each with dependent variable of cus12 and a different list of independent variables?

Comment: One model, if it's possible? Where I can analyze the dependence of the objective function (variable: "cus12") on independent variables. Now I have something like that (I edited post)

Comment: Transpose your data set first, see this blog post: https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2017/02/13/run-1000-regressions.html